# Changing SharePoint Calendar Event Form - Visual Customization and Conditional Inputs

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, javascript, calendar, custom-form

I need help with customizing the SharePoint calendar event creation form. Currently, when I create an event, it opens a default form.

Here is a picture of the default form:
[image]

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Visual Customization: Is there a way to change the look of the form - like layout, colors, or adding branding elements?

Conditional Inputs: More crucially, I want the form to show different inputs based on a user's selection. For instance, if a user selects a certain event type, I want additional relevant fields to show up. How can I implement this?

Any suggestions or guidance on how to make these changes, either through SharePoint's own settings or via custom scripting, would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online (M365)? If you are using SharePoint 2013 classic experience site, it is possible using custom scripting (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.) with content editor / script editor web part.

Comment: In the SharePoint 2013, you also could consider InfoPath. In the SharePoint Online, I suggest you use modern experience with Power Apps.